# WPF Button on some platforms flat on others not

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Why is this button on some platforms flat and on others there is a white border caused by a 3D-effect (seen on button press).

```
<Button Content="Print only"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,944,0,0" 
 Width="255" GotFocus="Button_GotFocus" Click="Button_Click_3" Background="#FF0074BD" 
 Foreground="White"  FontSize="22" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.706,-4.027" 
Height="54" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Comment: affected by Windows theme settings?

Comment: how can I make it always flat or where can I set those settings?

Comment: what is the OS version?

Comment: not wanted 3d effect is on windows 7

Comment: try [this](https://www.winhelp.us/disable-visual-effects-in-windows.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings the style did it for me:

```
<Button  Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" />
```